# Django & ajax : control the 'data' returned by Ajax query

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have two fields depending on a field.
until now I can make one field dependent but not both because i dont know how to control data variable of Ajax.

```
 $("#id_type1").change(function () {
  var url = $("#personForm").attr("data-tiers-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
  var typeID = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input
//  alert(countryId)
  $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
    url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
    data: {
      'tiers': typeID       // add the country id to the GET parameters
    },
    success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
      alert(data)
      $("#id_tiers").html(data);
      // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
    }
  });
});
```

this is the views that returns data it contains tree variables :

```
def load_tiers(request):
    tiers_id = request.GET.get('tiers')
    print(tiers_id)
    tiers = operation_Bancaire.objects.all().filter(type_tiers=tiers_id)
    #print(cities)
    frs="Fournisseur";
    clt="1";
    if tiers_id=="Fournisseur":
        frs = operation_Bancaire.objects.all().filter(type_tiers=tiers_id)
    elif tiers_id=="client":
        clt = operation_Bancaire.objects.all().filter(type_tiers=tiers_id)
    return render(request, 'appOne/city_dropdown_list_options.html', {'tiers': tiers,'frs':frs,'clt':clt})
```

I need to control this `data` : `$("#id_tiers").html(data);` to give `#id_tiers` just the value of `data['frs']` and not `'tiers','frs','clt'`

this what data contains :

[image]

can you please help me to achieve this because i'm new to Ajax, and js in general.

Comment: Can you please show us what the response looks like?  EG, what is the value of `data` inside your `success` function?  Or provide the Django template you use when rendering the response from `load_tiers`.

Comment: <option value="">---</option>
<option value="frs">563</option>
<option value="clt">43</option>

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest that you alter your Python endpoint or create a new one, so you can simply return JSON to your AJAX call?  It's more difficult to parse HTML to get the value you want than if you send the response as JSON.

```
def load_tiers_json(request):
    tiers_id = request.GET.get('tiers')
    tiers = operation_Bancaire.objects.all().filter(type_tiers=tiers_id)
    frs="Fournisseur";
    clt="1";
    if tiers_id=="Fournisseur":
        frs = operation_Bancaire.objects.all().filter(type_tiers=tiers_id)
    elif tiers_id=="client":
        clt = operation_Bancaire.objects.all().filter(type_tiers=tiers_id)
    return JsonResponse({'tiers': tiers,'frs':frs,'clt':clt})
```

Then in your AJAX call, get the key you want from the returned `data`:

```
$("#id_type1").change(function () {
  var url = $("#personForm").attr("data-tiers-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
  var typeID = $(this).val();  
  $.ajax({                       
    url: url,                    
    data: {
      'tiers': typeID     
    },
    success: function (data) {   
      $("#id_tiers").html(data.frs);
    }
  });
});
```

Of course, you will need to alter your Django `urls.py` to expose this new endpoint, and change the `url` value in JavaScript call to use the new endpoint.

Comment: It seems like a good solution, but where should I call 'appOne/city_dropdown_list_options.html'  , because this template is where I have the options that takes 'tiers', 'clt' and 'frs' as values ?

Comment: for example :  <option value="">---------</option>
{% for t in tiers %}
<option value="{{ t.tiers }}">{{ t.tiers }}</option>
{% endfor %}

Comment: If you want to have an endpoint that returns the rendered select widget, then leave your original endpoint intact, and create a new one as I suggested just for the AJAX call to use. But, that seems like it might be a separate question to this one.

Comment: but how can I associate between the two endpoints. Sorry I'm not used to Ajax yet